# c++ struct and "expected primary-expression" error

Tags: c++

It's easier to explain with some code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct test {
    int one;
    int two;
};

void insertdata(test & info)
{
    cin >> info.one;
    cin >> info.two;
}

int doitnow(test mytable[])
{
    test info;
    int i = 0;

    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        insertdata(test & info);
        mytable[i] = info;
    }

    return i;
}

int main()
{
    int total;
    test mytable[10];

    total = doitnow(test mytable[]);
    cout << total;
}
```

So, I need to pass info by reference to the function insertdata, I need to use that function in doitnow to fill up a table and I need to show in the main function the number of items inserted in doitnow. I keep getting errors when I try to call functions:

```
teste.cpp: In function ‘int doitnow(test*)’:
teste.cpp:21:29: error: expected primary-expression before ‘&’ token
insertdata(test & info);

teste.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
teste.cpp:33:30: error: expected primary-expression before ‘mytable’
total = doitnow(test mytable[]);
```

So, probably it's an obvious mistake but I'm a beginner at this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `test& info` is a **definition**. If you pass something to a function, you write an **expression** like `info`. It is **automatically** passed by reference because you specified `info` as a reference in the formal parameter list.

   You also wrote

   ```
   mytable[i] = info;
   ```

   and **not**

   ```
   mytable[i] = test & info;
   ```

   didn't ya?

   Use `insertdata(info);` instead.
2. Same goes for arrays. Use `doitnow(test)` instead.

Comment: Well, thank you sir. It solves the problem and makes sense.